# WPrinterJob_drawDIBImage InternalError when printing

Tags: java, image, printing

When trying to print a JPEG via a FileInputStream using the java Print Service API, we sometimes get the following Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Problem in WPrinterJob_drawDIBImage
    at sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob.drawDIBImage(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob.drawDIBImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WPathGraphics.drawImageToPlatform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.PathGraphics.drawImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.PathGraphics.drawImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.ImagePrinter.print(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.printPage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.printableJob(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.print(Unknown Source)
    at com.magicmemories.mpower.printing.AbstractPrinter.printDoc(Unknown Source)
    at com.magicmemories.mpower.printing.JPEGPrinter.print(Unknown Source)
    at com.magicmemories.mpower.printing.PrintProducer.print(Unknown Source)
    at com.magicmemories.mpower.product.D2PProducer.produce(Unknown Source)
    at com.magicmemories.mpower.tasks.PrintProductTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.magicmemories.mpower.tasks.PrintProductTask.call(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

The code that does the printing looks like this:

```
Doc printDoc = new SimpleDoc(new FileInputStream(jpegFile), DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG, null);
DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();
printJob.print(printDoc, printAttributes);
```

The actual JPEG that we print is dynamically generated - it is typically around 2MB. I have taken some images that failed to print and put them through a test script that makes the same calls to the API, so I am confident that there is nothing wrong with the images themselves.

The Exception does not occur every time, only about once every 50 or 100 prints. It has been seen on 32bit Java 6 Oracle JVMs, both update 26 and update 30. Since it is intermittent we assumed it was some kind of memory issue. We have monitored the application in jconsole while it was printing, and the Exception has been thrown when it had over 100MB of heap space free. Currently the application is running with 1GB of heap space on a WinXP box with 2GB RAM. We have put in a purchase order for more RAM so that we can try upping the heap space, but as it doesn't seem to be reaching its limit anyway we are not optimistic that this will fix it.

While we are waiting for our extra RAM to arrive is there anything else we could do to try to fix this problem?